# My music seems to be in "unknown artist" in everywhere but banshee

Tags: ubuntu-one, banshee, tag, ogg-vorbis

recently Banshee has decided to change my ogg files to "unknown artist" everywhere else but Banshee.

I don't know what's wrong with them but Ubuntu One and Android Music player can't read the artist tag anymore. They used to work however, most of my collection (500+ songs) show up as "unknown"

I have always kept "Write metadata to files" switched on.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks,

Joe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the file properties in Nautilus, and see if they have the tags still. If they don't, then you can manually edit them in Banshee and see if they keep the tags (just to be sure it wasn't some one time glitch).

If they don't keep the tags, you can use a tag editor like [Puddletag](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/) to manually add the tags.

Comment: Right, i'll have a try. If they don't show up, I'll make a script to fix them automatically. I can't be bothered to go through 500 files D:

Comment: I posted the code for anyone with trouble too https://gist.github.com/1156807

Comment: @Joe Simpson: if (you think) this is a bug in Banshee, please report a bug!

Comment: I will do that then! :D